# How can I build biceps without supinating the wrist?

Tags: biceps, arms, curls

I was born without the ability to supinate (turn my wrist so my palm faces upwards) my wrist. This is a problem only on my right hand. Therefore I can’t do regular curls, preacher curls or concentration curls. I can and am doing hammer curls. I have access to dumbells, kettle bells, and a lat machine (and body weight ofc).

Comment: So I'm assuming you also can't do underhand chin-ups? Can you turn your hand so that you thumb is pointing towards yourself while you do the curl (like hammercurls)?

Comment: Yeah. I am only doing hammer curls right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things to consider would be [deadlifts](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/ErectorSpinae/BBDeadlift.html) and [barbell rows](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/BackGeneral/BBBentOverRow.html). Done correctly there's not much movement in your wrist for those, and the deadlift will train your [biceps isometrically while the barbell row will do concentric](http://www.exrx.net/Kinesiology/Glossary.html).

It's a little soap-box-y, but I'd add that except for a very small portion of bodybuilders, most everyone would be ***much*** better off doing compound barbell lifts. Targeting individual muscles in isolation (curls, skull crushers, etc) are a great way to build imbalances and tendinitis.

So, while you may feel dismayed that you can't curl, you're probably better off anyway.